# How to solve the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error when creating a factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a model

```
class Income < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :income_type
  has_one :order

  validates_associated :income_type
  validates_presence_of :income_type
```

I create a factory for her

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :income do
    income_type
    amount { 100.0 }
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work and throws an error

```
Failure/Error: let!(:income) { create(:income) }

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Error
```

Comment: what does your `IncomeType` model looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it happens due to validation of `income_type`.
If you have a factory for `income_type`. You can do it two ways.
Provide `income_type` directly

```rb
let(:income_type) { create(:income_type) }
let!(:income) { create(:income, income_type: income_type) }
```

or define an association inside the `income` factory.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :income do
    association(:income_type)
    amount { 100.0 }
  end
end
```